# Can the referees self-evaluate during the breaks/intervals?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

During football matches intervals, between halves or before overtime, are the referees able to take a look at the dubious episodes of the first half?  Should they be able to?

Comment: Somewhat related: [What do football (soccer) referees do during halftime?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/15623)

Comment: The question sounds differents but that one, answer also to my question so is it right to close this one

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they can review fragments if they want to and if it is available. Whether they should or not is an opinion. I'm not even sure myself if I'd want to.

Comment: Please add sources. Otherwise, this answer becomes completely subjective and doesn't add any value.

Comment: There is no source as there is no specific rule that disallows reviewing fragments during halftime. I m not aware of any additional league or championship rules however. It becomes subjective when you state that this should be done or not. @gdrt

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer#help-post-body)